# Generate xml String from a xsd file in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have a big schema file (`.xsd`) that has choices that you can choose from:

```
<xs:element name="MyData">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="AAA" type="AAAType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="BBB" type="BBBType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="CCC" type="CCCType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="DDD" type="DDDType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="EEE" type="EEEType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="FFF" type="FFFType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="GGG" type="GGGType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="HHH" type="HHHType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="III" type="IIIType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="JJJ" type="JJJType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="KKK" type="KKKType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="LLL" type="LLLType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="MMM" type="MMMType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="NNN" type="NNNType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="OOO" type="OOOType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="PPP" type="PPPType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="QQQ" type="QQQType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="RRR" type="RRRType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="SSS" type="SSSType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="TTT" type="TTTType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="UUU" type="UUUType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="VVV" type="VVVType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="WWW" type="WWWType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="XXX" type="XXXType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="YYY" type="YYYType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="ZZZ" type="ZZZType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Each type has its own sequences and complex types. Is there a way I can program something in Java where I give it the choice as a String, the program looks in the schema file and outputs a XML String? Similar to how you can create a XML file in Eclipse given the schema, I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: IntelliJ does this easily: Right click on the xsd and ask the IDE to create an XML for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; however, I want to do this with code.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at JAXB, which reads schema files and generates Java classes that follow the rules set in your XSD. It basically creates POJO objects, which have a bunch of setters to easily populate the required XML data.

JAXB is commonly used, and worthwhile learning anyway.

See the official documentation here

[Lesson: Introduction to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)

Comment: Would you know how to do this with ADB? Just found out company wants to use that. I looked in the documentation but it's not that good.

Comment: I have only come across ADB in axis2, which is used for SOAP request. Here a link that may help [Axis2 Databinding Framework](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/adb/adb-howto.html)

Comment: Yea, I saw that too. Not that extensive, unfortunately.